# Socket.io return server response

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have an API like this:

```
function movePlayer(x, y){
    if (x < 0 || y < 0) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

and now I want to change only this function so that the if-else is on the server side like this:

Client side:

```
function movePlayer(x, y){
    var result;
    socket.emit('move_player', {
        _x: x,
        _y: y
    });
    socket.on('move_finished', function(data){
        result = data._result;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Server side:

```
var result;
socket.on('move_player', function(data){
    if (data._x < 0 || data._y < 0) result = false;
    else result = true;
    socket.emit('move_finished', {_result: result});
});
```

But it won't work since the server's response is asynchronous and the client side won't wait to get the response. So is there any way of doing it by just change the function definition only?

Comment: I think you will need to use some Promise to wait the result https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise

Comment: @Jerome But how can I `return result;` in the `then()` method of a promise?

Comment: Yes you should be able to do it, look my answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's not really good but I'm not a pro of Promise, I hope someone more qualified will come here

```js
//somewhere else
aFunction().then((result) => {
            //do something with this result
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })



aFunction = function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
      //some code that generates your result 
        if (result) {
            resolve(result);
        } else {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```